# nested numbering list in mediawiki

Tags: html, css, mediawiki, nested-lists

I'm looking for the way to use **nested numbering index** of lists in MediaWiki pages. I want to get the following:

```
1 item "1"
2 item "2"
  2.1 item "2.1"
      2.2.1 item "2.2.1"
      2.2.2 item "2.2.2"
  2.2 item "2.2"
3 item "3"
```

I've found some CSS/HTML working code for HTML pages but I cannot fit it in a MediaWiki page.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: You can use html to add lists in MediaWiki, so just add the list with `<ol>`-tags as you wish, give them the classes they need, and add the CSS in `MediaWiki:Commons.css` as you would normally do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
<ol class="nested-list">
    <li>item "1"
    <li>item "2"
        <ol>
            <li>item "2.1"
            <li>item "2.2"
        </ol>
    </li>           
</ol>
```

And then in [`MediaWiki:Commons.css`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:CSS) (if [$wgUseSiteCss](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgUseSiteCss) is `true`, as per default), add something like this:

```
ol.nested-list { counter-reset: item }
ol.nested-list li { display: block }
ol.nested-list li:before { content: counters(item, ".") " "; counter-increment: item }
```